# batches and requests_per_second in ElasticSearch Delete By Query API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading Delete By Query API from here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query.

I am confused how to do `batches` and `requests_per_second` work for this API. I tried to check the source code https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch, but could not find the properly related code.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Delete By Query issues queries against your index. Matching documents are deleted via bulk requests. You can use the `scroll_size` parameter to set how many documents are deleted per bulk request - this is often referred to as the "batch size". To throttle the operation, you can set `requests_per_second` to a positive decimal value. How this value corresponds to wait times is explained in their documentation:

> requests_per_second can be set to any positive decimal number (1.4, 6, 1000, etc) and throttles rate at which _delete_by_query issues batches of delete operations by padding each batch with a wait time. The throttling can be disabled by setting requests_per_second to -1.
>
> The throttling is done by waiting between batches so that scroll that _delete_by_query uses internally can be given a timeout that takes into account the padding. The padding time is the difference between the batch size divided by the requests_per_second and the time spent writing. By default the batch size is 1000, so if the requests_per_second is set to 500:
>
> target_time = 1000 / 500 per second = 2 seconds
>   wait_time = target_time - write_time = 2 seconds - .5 seconds = 1.5 seconds

Comment: Thx for the explanation. But I still have no idea what values I should set for those parameters to make the deletion run faster and not to overload ES at the same time. It's hard to do many experiments as it's time-consuming to create a large index file for me to play with every time.

Comment: I'd suggest you leave them alone (accept the defaults) and only start to tweak them if you are encountering issues. The optimal values for these likely depend on your data and workload.

Comment: That's the question I had in my mind. In what case should I use `requests_per_second = 5`? In what case should I use `requests_per_second = 1000`? How about tuning `scroll_size `? I am dealing with mostly 1GB index files and need to avoid overloading the ES server. I want to have some idea what values I should try. It's not easy to recreate the indices and delete them again.

Comment: How much time do you want to wait, and allow ES time to perform other tasks, between batches in a Delete By Query, if it's just a little maybe 5 is good, if it's longer then maybe 1000 would be better. If you want the execution of batch to be faster you can reduce the `scroll_size`, by default it is 1000, if you want the Delete By Query to complete in fewer requests, increase it.

Comment: I think I get the idea now. Small `requests_per_second` means potential longer idle time on ES, so it can process more requests from other tasks. Big `requests_per_second ` means ES should focus on this task as much as it can and put less time/resource on other tasks running at the same time. Big `scroll_size` means for one request, do a lot before stopping. Small `scroll_size ` means do for one request, do a little before stopping. Seem that I cannot avoid some effort of tweaking parameters before getting a reasonable speed for my delete_by_query task.

Answer (score 0):

Add `request_timeout` to the `delete_by_query`:

Example of 120 seconds timeout:

```
response = es.delete_by_query(
  index=<requested-index>,
  body=<body>,
  request_timeout=120 # Seconds Units
)
```