# Elasticsearch delete By Query not completing deletes

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to delete a large number of documents in a 5.5 Elasticsearch cluster. I know the optimal way to do this is to rebuild the cluster without the intended documents, but that's not possible in our case. I run the following query that deletes documents from a subset of the indexes in the cluster:

```
GET myindex_1*/doc_type/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "typeCode": [
              "Filtered_Type"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "createdDateUTC": {
              "lt": "2017-10-28"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It starts deleting documents for a couple of hours but then just stops and I have to kick it off again. Any ideas why it stops running the delete query?

Just a note, I'm using Kibana to run the query and the request times out on the client side when though I can see it continues deleting on the backend.

Comment: isn't it because of timeout? Could you try POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-delete-by-query.html):

> By default _delete_by_query uses scroll batches of 1000. You can change the batch size with the scroll_size URL parameter:

```
POST twitter/_delete_by_query?scroll_size=5000
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information here about batching and batch sizes here:

- [batches and requests_per_second in ElasticSearch Delete By Query API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50686548/109941)

And since you'll need to scroll through one to many batches to delete all of the documents found by your query, you can find more information about scrolling here:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: would a default batch size of 1000 cause it to stop deleting documents eventually? And increasing it to 5000 prevent this from happening?

Comment: I updated my answer. Simply increasing the batch size to `5000` isn't sufficient. You need to think in terms of scrolling through all the batches and deleting all of the documents in each batch.